# How to retrieve a model's record attributes including has_many ids as a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

Assume I have the following class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
end
```

And I'm initializing the following record:
`user = User.new(first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe", address_ids: [1, 2, 3])`

There already exists a convenient method provided by Rails to retrieve the attributes of a model's record:
`user.attributes # => {first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe"}`

However, I also need to get a hash that contains the `address_ids` as well, that is:

```
user.attributes_with_has_many_associations 
# => {first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe", address_ids: [1, 2, 3]}
```

I'm looking for a *general* way to do this on any given record(i.e. does not involve reflecting the associations to pull the attributes and end up the polluting the model itself, after all I'm looking for a way to do this purely for testing purposes) or at least to have a method isolated in the test code.

Comment: shouldn't User.address_ids give you exactly that? If you already save the ids as an array you can retrieve the same like that, no?

Comment: There's no built-in way of doing this. Just add the associations you're after manually, ie `user.attributes.tap { |a| a[:address_ids] = a.address_ids }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is a Rails method but you could define it yourself.

```
def attributes_with_has_many_associations
  attributes.merge(
    self
      .class
      .reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)
      .map(&:plural_name)
      .map { |as| { as.to_sym => self.send(as) } }
      .reduce(&:merge)
  )
end
```